# How to round values in pyplot table

Tags: python, matplotlib, rounding

I joined two tables into one using pandas Concat function. I then put them in a pyplot table. I end up with a table where all the values have 1 decimal. The original tables did not have the decimal before concatenating.

How can I get a table without decimals?

I tried rounding the values in the tables before concatenating but this does not work.

This is my code:

```
frames = [country_tab, country_birth_tab] 

result = pd.concat(frames, axis=1)
#print(result)

ax = plt.subplot(111, frame_on=False) # no visible frame
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)  # hide the x axis
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)  # hide the y axis

table2 = table(ax, result) 
table2.auto_set_font_size(False)
table2.set_fontsize(16)
table2.scale(4,4)
```

[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZV9P4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case `result = result.astype(int)` also should work. astype(int) is help to convert your float to int. So your columns will be integer.

Also that line can work your code.

```
result[["Column1", "Column2"]] = result[["Column1", "Column2"]].astype(int)
```

So your final code is :

```
frames = [country_tab, country_birth_tab] 

result = pd.concat(frames, axis=1)

result = result.astype(int)

ax = plt.subplot(111, frame_on=False) # no visible frame
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)  # hide the x axis
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)  # hide the y axis

table2 = table(ax, result) 
table2.auto_set_font_size(False)
table2.set_fontsize(16)
table2.scale(4,4)
```

Comment: @havaey happy to hear that :) Happy coding